# Is this language regular ? [automata]

Tags: automata, regular-language

Is this a regular language :

$$L = \{w : w \in \{a,b\}^*\text{ and }abw = wba\}$$

Does my automata only need to start with $a$ and $b$, then loop on $a,b$ and finish with $b\to a$, or do I don't understand the language?

Comment: A point of information: *automata* is plural. The singular is *automaton*.

Comment: What do you think $L$ looks like? Can you describe in simple terms what words are in $L$?

Comment: Oops, my bad. English is not my native language!

Comment: That’s okay: an awful lot native speakers of English make the same mistake. (The word actually comes from Greek.)

Comment: abba or
abaaaba or
abaaaaaaba or
abbbbba and so on of course..

Comment: Those don’t work: $abba\notin L$, because $ababba\ne abbaba$, and the others have the same problem. However, $aba\in L$: $ab(aba)=ababa=(aba)ba$. Similarly, $ababa\in L$: $ab(ababa)=abababa=(ababa)ba$.

Comment: I knew I read it wrong, just could not figure out what it was. thanks

Comment: You’re welcome; I’ve expanded that comment into a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Prove that $L$ is generated by the regular expression $(ab)^*a$. If $L_0$ is the language generated by $(ab)^*a$, it’s not hard to prove that $L_0\subseteq L$. To prove that $L\subseteq L_0$, I suggest assuming that $L_0\setminus L\ne\varnothing$, letting $w$ be a word of minimal length in $L_0\setminus L$, and getting a contradiction. (If you get stuck finding the contradiction, feel free to leave a comment.)

Comment: I'm getting the impression that you are telling me it is non-regular but I see it as a regular language. Is it regular or not ?

Comment: @TUQWPORA32: I’m saying that it’s generated by a regular expression, so I’m certainly saying that it’s regular!